# Create a free sharepoint online site (office 365)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have created a free sharepoint online site (office 365) some months ago. But now that is not working.
Then I tried to create a new free office 365 site. It seems like can't create a free site? We need to pay for it.
Can somebody tell me how to create a free office 365 site?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also create a new Enterprise 3 subscription [here](https://portal.office.com/Signup/Signup.aspx?OfferId=B07A1127-DE83-4a6d-9F85-2C104BDAE8B4&dl=ENTERPRISEPACK&Country=US&culture=en-us&ali=1#0). As far as I know there is no limit (a colleague of mine has 5).

- It includes Developer's Site
- NAPA is available
- you can connect to Visual Studio, upload solutions, etc.
- the trial period is 30 days + 30 days extra time before you lose access to your data

If you really want to work and keep your data there, you should just pay, but if it is only for testing purposes (especially something that you're not sure and may break your tenant) then I think it is even recommended by Microsoft to use test/temporary subscriptions.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about a free site. I think you had use a trial period and this time is now over. You must buy, at minimum, one User licence to continue using your Site.

Comment: As I remember we can create a free trial site. But now I couldn't..

Comment: You can get an Office 365 Developer Site free for 30 days. After that it's $99 per year.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179924%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem over the past couple weeks as well. Under the current procedure, it appears you have to assign your admin account a license after creating the O365 trial account.

You can assign the user account a license from the admin dashboard by going to users > active users > select admin account > edit assigned licence > select Office 365 licence.